# d3js graph throwing Uncaught Type Error: Already checked with JsHint

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am getting an uncaught Type error on my graph code that is throwing a bunch of code like this

```
 Object function n(n){n.each(function(){var n,s=Xo.select(this),l=this.__chart__||e,f=this.__chart__=e.copy(),h=null==c?f.ticks?f.ticks.apply(f,a):f.domain():c,g=null==t?f.tickFormat?f.tickFormat.apply(f,a):bt:t,p=s.selectAll(".tick").data(h,f),v=p.enter().insert("g",".domain").attr("class","tick").style("opacity",Aa),d=Xo.transition(p.exit()).style("opacity",Aa).remove(),m=Xo.transition(p).style("opacity",1),y=Ri(f),x=s.selectAll(".domain").data([0]),M=(x.enter().append("path").attr("class","domain"),Xo.transition(x));v.append("line"),v.append("text");var _=v.select("line"),b=m.select("line"),w=p.select("text").text(g),S=v.select("text"),k=m.select("text");switch(r){case"bottom":n=Ho,_.attr("y2",u),S.attr("y",Math.max(u,0)+o),b.attr("x2",0).attr("y2",u),k.attr("x",0).attr("y",Math.max(u,0)+o),w.attr("dy",".71em").style("text-anchor","middle"),M.attr("d","M"+y[0]+","+i+"V0H"+y[1]+"V"+i);break;case"top":n=Ho,_.attr("y2",-u),S.attr("y",-(Math.max(u,0)+o)),b.attr("x2",0).attr("y2",-u),k.attr("x",0).attr("y",-(Math.max(u,0)+o)),w.attr("dy","0em").style("text-anchor","middle"),M.attr("d","M"+y[0]+","+-i+"V0H"+y[1]+"V"+-i);break;case"left":n=Fo,_.attr("x2",-u),S.attr("x",-(Math.max(u,0)+o)),b.attr("x2",-u).attr("y2",0),k.attr("x",-(Math.max(u,0)+o)).attr("y",0),w.attr("dy",".32em").style("text-anchor","end"),M.attr("d","M"+-i+","+y[0]+"H0V"+y[1]+"H"+-i);break;case"right":n=Fo,_.attr("x2",u),S.attr("x",Math.max(u,0)+o),b.attr("x2",u).attr("y2",0),k.attr("x",Math.max(u,0)+o).attr("y",0),w.attr("dy",".32em").style("text-anchor","start"),M.attr("d","M"+i+","+y[0]+"H0V"+y[1]+"H"+i)}if(f.rangeBand){var E=f,A=E.rangeBand()/2;l=f=function(n){return E(n)+A}}else l.rangeBand?l=f:d.call(n,f);v.call(n,l),m.call(n,f)})} has no method 'tick
```

which is obviously coming from the d3 source code. I don't know what I am doing wrong . Please advise on what I should do to fix this.

here is a link to my code http://brussels-court-74.pancakeapps.com/index.html

Comment: I can't do a jsfiddle because it requires a json file so I put it up in the best way possible

Answer (score 0):

There is no method `tick` on `d3.svg.axis`. There is however a method `ticks`.

The API reference is here. https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes

Comment: sorry now it says that data is not defined